# Dynamic Binding / Bind Path in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Is there any way to dynamically bind the value in aurelia?

test.js

```
export class test{
    constructor(){
        var self = this;
        self.what='firstname';
        self.firstname = 'John';
        self.lastname = 'Doe';
    }
}
```

test.html

```
<template>
   Input <input type="text" value.bind="what" />
   output: <input type="text" value.bind="${what}" />
</template>
```

--- Not working

What I want to achieve is :

1. If I write 'firstname' in the Input, It will show 'John' in the Output.
2. If I write 'lastname' in the Input, It will show 'Doe' in the Output.

This can be needed when we need the binding path to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do something very strange... Anyway, that's how you can do it:

```
 Input <input type="text" value.bind="what">
 Output <input type="text" value.bind="$this[what]">
```

In this way, if you type 'firstname' in the input, you'll get 'John' in the output. However, ***this is not recommended***, be careful when using `$this`. Also, since you're binding things, I think Aurelia will create a new property if you type a non-existent property, which might cause you memory problems. If I were you I would try to solve this problem in a whole different way.

`$this` = your view model instance

Comment: Thanks a lot. This can be useful when we need the binding path to be dynamic.

Comment: If this is solved your problem, please accept it as the correct answer